# Parsing nested JSON using JSON Schema or Classes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a large nested JSON response in following sample format:

```json
{
  "type": "folder",
  "path": "Path1",
  "owner": "user1",
  "entries": [{
    "type": "folder",
    "path": "Path2",
    "owner": "user1",
    "entries": [{
        "type": "folder",
        "path": "Path3",
        "owner": "user1"
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "path": "FullFilePath1",
        "owner": "user1"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

I wanted to extract all the file type with selected keys and also add additional keys:

```json
{
  "type": "file",
  "path": "FullFilePath1",
  "Application": "My Application",
  "UpdatedTime": "Time"
}
```

I am using nodejs. I need inputs in parsing the JSON file in best way. I was trying to check if I can use JSON Schema and Classes to do this but still didnt get through.

Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with JSON, you can simply load it into a JavaScript variable using require:

```
let data = require('./data.json');
```

You can then loop the variable for all entries tag

```
let fileData = require('./data.json');
let allEntries = [];
loadEntries(fileData);
function loadEntries(data) {
    if(data.entries) {
        for (let index = 0; index < data.entries.length; index++) {
            const entry = data.entries[index];
            // Do something with the entry
            allEntries.push(entry);
            loadEntries(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Pascal. I was looking for a way to utilize JSON Schema or classes to parse it. Something like, I define a model beforehand and then pass the complete JSON or filter JSON (type: files) to the model and it structures the output as required (like adding additional keys or splitting certain values into multiple keys or removing certain keys).